# Text size in Google script dialog

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google script attached to a spreadsheet that creates a dialog message but I want to increase the size of the message text. Here is the relevant bit of the script:-

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('Word Spiral Hint Mate', 'Which question do you want help with?', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
 var qhint = response.getResponseText() ;
 hintq =  qhint * 1 + 2;
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Questions");
 var hintCell = sheet.getRange((hintq),4);
 var hCell = hintCell.getValue();
var responsea = ui.prompt('Word Spiral Hint Mate', 'Hint for Question '+ response.getResponseText() + ' is ' + hCell , ui.ButtonSet.OK);
```

How do I do it - any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of text in the prompt dialog but you can use the HTMLService to build your own dialog box and there you have the to customize the layout with HTML and CSS.

See [sample code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface).

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished that by modifying the line:
var response = ui.prompt('Word Spiral Hint Mate', 'Which question do you want help with?', ui.ButtonSet.OK);

to:

var response = ui.prompt('Word Spiral Hint Mate. Which question do you want help with?', ' ', ui.ButtonSet.OK);

The second set of single quotes (' ') make the first set larger.